# File - Import Export menu is dangerous

Tags: interface

Twice when I have wanted to import an object, I have inadvertently gone to the export menu and exported a empty object over the
mesh that i want to import. Now my work is gone.

Is there a way to edit the file menu to make a space between import and export?

Comment: Not to sound rude but perhaps slow down and read what you're doing? :)

Comment: yes I learn it the hard way :) but a clear import export menu would nice

Comment: Did you try to look for your file in the auto-backup? It's always a good idea to drop your work in some extra cache like a cloud based storage? I have more than 2 copies of my work when I am working on paid projects and update them via a console at the end of every day.

Comment: I have noticed when importing files the scaling can be strange depending on the file type.

Comment: I've almost voted to close the question, because it's not clear what you're asking. You're writing about import and export, but it sounds like you mean to write about saving and opening.

Comment: What's not clear? The question is about inserting a separator between "Import" and "Export" in the File menu. And there is a solution that does not require a compiler. Perhaps it will not solve the confusion, but there is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since the v2.5 rewrite, much of the Blender GUI is defined by Python scripts. That means it can be changed with only a text editor, no compiler setup needed.

But you will need write rights to modify the script files. And that depends on how you installed Blender. I assume the usual install on Windows allows it.

These steps use the built-in Text Editor in Blender.

1. Right-click on the File menu.
2. In that short menu, choose "Edit source". Blender will report that "space_info.py" has been loaded into the Text Editor.
3. Switch to the Text Editor.
4. Switch the file to the "space_info.py" script file.
5. Use "Edit > Find" to search for "file_import". It will find a line like `layout.menu("INFO_MT_file_import", icon='IMPORT')`.
6. Copy a `layout.separator()` line and paste it after the line in the previous step. You will have to copy and match the empty space at the beginning too, it is important for Python.
7. Save the script file.
8. Restart Blender.

You should now see a separator between Import and Export in the File menu.

Reinstalling or updating Blender will remove your changes, so you will have to repeat this when you update. A backup of the script file would not solve this, because it would conflict with changes in the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can increase the space between specific menu items, but you would have to edit the same interface layout file whenever you update Blender.

One thing you could try is to experiment with changing the font size settings for Blender, found in the "system" tab of the User preferences window. Increasing the value in the "DPI" pane of the window associated with this tab would make the text in the menu larger, but it would also make all of the other text in the instance of Blender larger, too.

It is possible, however, that someone else with the skill set necessary to craft a new UI has made the modification you seek. You might try asking in some of the community forums on such sites as Blender Artists, Blender Nation, or others.

I know of that least one person that has crafted a custom UI, [Blender Sensei](https://blendersensei.com/), but I don't follow it, haven't used it, and so neither recommend nor discourage it.

Finally, while the new (since version 2.72) Pie Menus feature does not yet seem to be enabled for the file menu, I would expect some future version of this feature will deal with the file menu.